# Raspbian: reduce number of tty

Tags: raspbian, boot

When my b+ (raspbian 3.18.12+) boots, it actually loads 6 tty.

Is there a way to reduce the number of tty?

Comment: Could you check if this procedure works out: http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/disable_extra_ttys (I have no raspbian available right now and arch seems to use a different sytem (systemd/logind)).

Comment: With this procedure, I can't access to my raspberry anymore
$> ssh -vvv user@ip  => ssh: connect to host  "ip" port "X": Connection refused

Comment: All you need to do is comment out the lines in `inittab` -- ignore that bit about `/etc/securetty` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When my b+ (raspbian 3.18.12+) boots, it actually loads 6 tty.

If you look at `ls /dev`, you'll see the kernel in fact creates **64** `tty` devices that are exported by `udev`, not including special ones such as the serial port.  I'm not sure what the reason for this is; I could not find a kernel config option for changing it, but you can "hide" them by [not having them exported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25023/25985) to `/dev`.  However, I'd guess the logic is better too many than too little since if they are not used for anything, they do not represent any use of resources beyond perhaps a few bytes of kernelspace (if that).

But I think what you are actually referring to are the login `getty` applications that run by default on tty1-6.  These are started by `init`.

These use almost no resources as well, so if that is your justification, save yourself some time and don't worry about it.  On a system using SysV init such as Raspbian Wheezy, they'll probably show up with `ps -A | grep getty`; there's one on the serial port too, which makes 7.  Pick one and have a look in `top` at the `RES` and `SHR` numbers.  I get ~1600 bytes for the former and ~1500 bytes for the latter, which is *shared* memory.  All seven of them will be sharing that, so what each one really adds to RAM is -- gasp -- ~100 bytes of memory.  Closing six of them would therefore only save you a little over a 1/2 kB, i.e., **0.0001 %** of the 512 MB total.

It is not hard to do if you want though.  This is specific to SysV init, which is Raspbian Wheezy; Jessie and other pi distros use a different init system by default.  Open `/etc/inittab` for editing and find this section:

```
# Note that on most Debian systems tty7 is used by the X Window System,
# so if you want to add more getty's go ahead but skip tty7 if you run X.
#
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty --noclear 38400 tty1 
2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
```

You can comment out any of those lines but I would leave at least the first one.  This will prevent the spawning of `getty` on those ttys.  It won't prevent the ttys from existing, but all you will see on them is a blank screen, unless some output has been directed there (e.g., try as root, sudo will not work: `echo "hello!" > /dev/tty4` and then switch over to look).

Comment: I've commented the tty 3 to 6 and I can't ssh to my raspberry pi anymore

Comment: That is pretty odd.  I just tried this (commenting out 3-6) on a wheezy B and had no such problem.  Try uncommenting them without changing anything else just to confirm the issue.  Also, if you have a screen attach that and see if boot otherwise looks normal.

Comment: I've connected a keyboard to the raspberry and I've uncommented the lines. I can re access the pi by ssh. I can't try the procedure anymore until Monday. I keep you informed

Comment: You could also try leaving them uncommented, but change the `23` of the ones you don't want to `45`.  Those are the runlevels (1-5) these happen in; the default is 2, so the ones without that won't start then.  That maybe a more correct method.

Comment: I don't know why but after a second try, this answer works.