# Reading time off of a cellular modem with python 2.7 and pyserial

Tags: serial-console, python-2.x, timekeeping, modem

**TL;DR:**

I need to read the time off of my Hologram Nova USB cellular modem on `/dev/ttyACM0` and update the system clock after the pi restarts. I'd like to do it in Python but it isn't reading the serial tty correctly.

**My build**

- I'm running python 2.7.13 on Raspbian 9
- I'm using pyserial 3.2.1-1
- I have a Pi 3 b+
- The modem is a USB connected U-Blox SARA-U201 (AKA Hologram Nova)

**What works so far:**

- My cellular modem is sitting on `/dev/ttyACM0`

  - I can communicate with it using `screen /dev/ttyacm0 9600`
- I can get a time stamp in the `screen` session by typing `AT+CCLK?` and hitting `Enter`

Here is the output from the `screen` session

> AT+CCLK?
>
> +CCLK: "19/05/16,21:31:47-16"
>
> OK

**What doesn't work so far:**

- I have tried to use pyserial to interrogate the tty and return the time stamp.
- I have tried to create an `expect` script using `screen`

  - I'd prefer *not* to do this with an `expect` script when python is a lot better.
  - I'll post my source for `expect` if this can't be done in Python.

**Python Code:**

```
import serial
import time, sys
import datetime
response = ''
SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyACM0"
ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 5)
ser.write("AT+CCLK?\r")
response = ser.readline()
print response
```

When using the python console the line `ser.write("AT+CCLK?\r")` results in a **9** being returned on the next line. `response` remains empty and `ser.inWaiting()` is equal to 0. Here is the text returned from the tty:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Sep 26 2018, 18:42:22)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> import time, sys
>>> import datetime
>>> response = ''
>>> SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyACM0"
>>> ser = serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 5)
>>> ser.write("AT+CCLK?\r")
9
>>> response = ser.readline()
>>> print response
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: Hey there! The response text is listed above the picture but I'll go ahead and change it.

Comment: Ah sorry, haven't seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out I am an impatient man.

I was simply requesting the data too quickly; screen stays connected and shows it, Python is just too fast when it reads the input.

This code attempts to read the time from the modem at 2/10 of a second intervals for 20 seconds. If unsuccessful it sleeps for 20 seconds and then tries again. It will return the datetime string that is provided to the modem. That can be parsed from the "response" variable.

```
import serial
import time, sys
import datetime

i=0
time_found=False
response=''
SERIAL_PORT="/dev/ttyACM0"
ser=serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT, baudrate = 9600, timeout = 15)

while time_found==False:
        ser.write('AT+CCLK?\r')
        response = ser.readline()
        while "CCLK:" not in response:
                response=ser.readline()
                time.sleep(0.2)
                ++i
                if i==200:
                        break
        if "CCLK:" in response:
                time_found=True
        else:
                time.sleep(20)

print response
```

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> Setup  = Hologram Nova USB cellular modem on /dev/ttyACM0
>
> Can do = Terminal command AT+CCLK? replies +CCLK:
>   "19/05/16,21:31:47-16"
>
> How do in python?

***Answer***

Suggest 2 steps:

> 1. Verify serial OK by loop back on '/dev/serial0'.
> 2. Replace '/dev/serial0' by '/dev/ttyACM0' and try your luck on Hologram Nova.

***Update 2019may17hkt1628***

In case loopback /dev/serial0 works but /dev/ttyACM0 does not work, then it might be the external USB problem.  I usually recommend to use the powerful RealTerm to do troubleshooting.  You might might read the details in the second reference below.  ***RealTerm can send/receive long strings of file***, store data in files, new line setting, etc. So it is much faster than python and the not so powerful puTTY or TeraTerm.  I show below a couple of screen captures for your reference.  You might also like to read SparkFun for their recommendation of RealTerm (see reference below).  And in case you are trying USB/TTL cables, good quality USB cable is also important.  I usually recommend CH340 drivers, though Raspbian accepts PX2xxx drivers OK.

[image: superterm 1]

[image: superterm 2]

[image: usb serial cable]

**References**

*UART Serial Debugging Tips*

[[How to verify serial by loopback check?] Serial Communication from Raspbian using Python to Arduino](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/serial-communication-from-raspbian-using-python-to-arduino?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[[How to debug serial?] Serial to Arduino totally non-responsive](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96184/serial-to-arduino-totally-non-responsive/96264#96264)

*Terminal Emulators*

[Serial Terminal Basics (TeraTerm) - SparkFun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/tera-term-windows)

[RealTerm (Windows) - SparkFun Recommendation](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/real-term-windows)

> TeraTerm is awesome for simple ASCII-only serial terminal stuff, but
>   what if you need to send a string of binary values ranging from 0-255?
>   For that, we like to use RealTerm. RealTerm is designed specifically
>   for sending binary and other difficult-to-type streams of data, ...

*USB TTL*

[How many serial ports are on the Pi 3?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3)

[Options to add 20 UART to RPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98393/options-to-add-20-uart-to-rpi)

[Increase number of TTYs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98506/increase-number-of-ttys/98522#98522)

[Persistent [USB] Device Names on Raspberry Pi - Vrijdag 2015feb06](https://rolfblijleven.blogspot.com/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html)

***Program to setup serial on '/dev/serial0'***

```
from   time import sleep
import serial

serialPort0 = serial.Serial(port = '/dev/serial0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout= 1)
```

Comment: Lots to look into here! Thank you! The modem is directly connected into the pi, no cable. I'll try to use some of your suggested tools and read your links today. I will have to play more with it after work. I appreciate the information!

Comment: @Shrout1 You are welcome.  I suggest to also try USB/TTL cable, for easy swap testing, and also sooner or later you might need more than one UART channel.  Good luck and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Worked it out! I was trying to poll the TTY too quickly and so I was looking for a response before the modem could actually query the network. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: How nice!  I also learnt a lesson from your experiments.  I am thinking of adding a user programmable delay in my UART loopback program, so the user can adjust the delays.  You also remind me when I first played with a BlueTooth serial module.  I did not realize in the beginning that the blue tooth modules needs some time (in the order of milliseconds) to process the data from Rpi.  And after adding a wait-for-module-operation function, all problems disappeared!  Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

You have supplied insufficient information to provide a definitive answer.

It is most likely your modem is expecting a LF or CR/LF

Replace the \r with \n

read(30) is going to wait for 30 characters. You should use readline() or equivalent

Comment: I've also tried readline() and it didn't work, but thank you for the pointer! I can try a \n but I've never seen that in any guide anywhere... Using screen and the enter key it works

Comment: Modified the script to use `ser.readline()` and included a screenshot. What other information can I provide that will help to solve the issue? I'm happy to post anything that gets me closer to the solution. Also, I tried using `\n` instead of `\r` and `response` came back with my original query as though a new line had not been entered.

Comment: @Shrout1 DO NOT post images - copy text. You still appear to be sending a CR. You appear to be running as root - this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I will try it as a regular user as well, it’s possible that’s a part of the problem. The text responses are available above the screenshot. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that running this particular set of commands with sudo or as root doesn't have an impact. But thank you for pointing that out! Always something to keep an eye out for.